# Python creating a polynomial model with two input variables

Tags: regression, python, polynomial

I have data for two input variables x_1 and x_2 and one output variable y.  The two input variables seem to have a nonlinear relationship with y.  Here are the plots
[image]

[image]

So I am trying to fit a polynomial model for this data, but I'm not sure how to do this with python.  Should I just fit a two polynomial models - one for x_1 vs y and one for x_2 vs y.  Then fit a linear model for the output of the two polynomial models to get something of this form.

y=a(d*x_1^2+e*x_1+f)+b(g*x_2^2+h*x_2+i)+c

Is there a way to do this more efficiently with python (scikit-learn maybe?)

Comment: Yes, there is documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) on how to do this using scikit-learn.  You can create a design matrix with the polynomial terms you would like to include and use the LinearRegression() function from the linear_models module.

Comment: Have you thought about using the simple [scipy.stats.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) method directly on your two polynormial model ?

Comment: Thanks, scipy.stats.curve_fit looks like it might work.  what I ended up doing was creating the dataset (a^2,b^2,ab,a,b,1) for the two input variables a and b, then fitting a linear model to this new dataset.  It had an explained variance score of 0.999 so I think that is pretty good :)